# docker-compose restore mongo database every time collection deletes

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i want to be able to recreate some base data that is dumped when mongo-data folder is deleted and `docker-compose up` is called.
the problem that im facing is that app does not have `mongo`

these are my files:
docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/testapp
    environment:
      DB_URL: mongodb://test_mongo/appdb
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    image: "mongo:4.4.4"
    restart: always
    container_name: test_mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
      - "27018:27018"
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-data:/data/db
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.15.5

RUN mkdir -p /testapp
WORKDIR /testapp

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sh ./__backup__/db/restore.sh
sh ./__backup__/app/restore.sh

yarn install
yarn start:dev
```

**backup**/app/restore.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -d '/testapp/uploads' ]]
then
  tar -xvf ./uploads.tar.gz /testapp/
fi
```

**backup**/app/restore.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

until mongo --eval "print(\"waited for connection\")"
do
    sleep 1
done

if [[ ! -d '/testapp/mongo-data' ]]
then
    mongorestore --archive ./db.dump
fi
```

is there anyway to run these resotre.sh files after mongo service is up or running mongo from app?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to restore the MongoDB to a certain state every time your app launches, and you're asking if there's a way to do it after MongoDB container launches.

There's a tool called [docker-compose-wait](https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait), quoting from its GitHub README, it's a small command-line utility to wait for other docker images to be started while using docker-compose.

It's fairly simple to use it. Add it to the image, run `/wait` to wait for services to be up, and get on to whatever you want next.

So according to your current setup, your Dockerfile could be like this:

```
FROM node:14.15.5

## Add the wait script to the image
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.9.0/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait

RUN mkdir -p /testapp
WORKDIR /testapp

ADD . .

EXPOSE 3000

## Launch the wait tool and then your entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT /wait && /testapp/entrypoint.sh"
```

In which your `entrypoint.sh` was already written to call the restore script. In your docker-compose.yml, add environment variable to set up the services to be waited.

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/testapp
    environment:
      DB_URL: mongodb://test_mongo/appdb
      WAIT_HOSTS: mongo:27017
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    image: "mongo:4.4.4"
    restart: always
    container_name: test_mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
      - "27018:27018"
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-data:/data/db
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem is i dont have access to mongo image and executabels from app service and when i want to do restore, i get this error:
```app_1    | ./__backup__/db/restore.sh: 4: ./__backup__/db/restore.sh: mongorestore: not found```